# What is needed in a stable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I like horses a lot. I want to make some stables, so I can keep my horses in there, but how do I keep the horses in a single pen and not wandering around on the lead? What do I need build to keep the horses in place and to stop them from escaping?

Comment: This [tutorial on building a redstone horse-door](http://www.minecraftforum.net/news/869-community-creations-horse-door/) may be helpful.

Comment: Otherwise though you're asking primarily for opinions, which is off topic here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Why give an answer and then say, "Oh, By the way it's off-topic".

Comment: @Young The horse door may or may not help, as it's a matter of opinion/taste/needs. It's not an answer, it's an interesting related thing. Since I was also voting to close, I left a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should build a pen with fences, or make a barn with separate stalls. The exit would be a fence gate and the walls could either be 2 fences high or 3 block high walls. You could then open the fence gate and use a lead to bring them to the desired location and back again (unless you have a saddle, in which case you could obviously ride the horse to and from the desired location).

Comment: Do you need 2 fences high? I've kept my horses is one place with one fence, they don't seem to try and jump in 1.7.10, I wonder why my horses never escape.

Comment: @SadlyNot Although they don't attempt to jump, it is very easily done by accident when riding one.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. while testing out Timtech's idea I found that horses could go over a single fence. I doubled that. So with a two fence tall wall surrounding the horse I then added two trapdoors. These could be opened by hand on the horse. When reentering the stall the horse would step on two pressure plates. This closes the gate so I could tie up my horse and he wouldn't escape.

Comment: Good idea! I forgot about horse jump distance. Now that I've edited in the correct information, does my question count as correct?

Answer (score 2):

- Stalls
- Pastures
- Fences
- Gates
- Animals despawn if that can't move at least 20 blocks in any direction so make large stalls or stalls leading out to a fenced in pasture!
- I've never had any problems with horses jumping 1 post tall fences. If I'm riding a horse, I want to be able to jump the fence with it because they don't fit through gates.
- I recommend at least 1 hay bale per stall (so the horse can heal).
- It's always fun to have a racetrack or jumping arena.
- As Sylvia said, it's good to have a tack/feed room with chests of saddles, feed, etc.
- It's good to have a corral for new horses that don't have stalls yet.
- Have an anvil and name tags, or just plain signs, to put the names of the horses on.
- Have leads and fences around to tie horses up so they don't get lost. They aren't like dogs. They don't follow you, saddle or no saddle.
- If you plan on riding horses into their stalls, make sure the roof is high enough that you don't hit your head.
- And most of all, make your stable unique!!!!

Comment: +1 but I doubt that placed hay bales will affect the horse's health stats...

Answer (score 0):

In a horse stable u should have the basics (stalls.) u could also add things like hay and water or a pen on the out side of the stall/ a pasture with other horses so they can roam free in that pasture. Also it is a good Idea to have a tack room or a loft to store hay, feed, and saddles. Around my stable I have a couple of post to tie my horse up to. And I also have a couple of pens to put new horses in. Also I have some opsticles for my horse to jump over for fun or just or to test the height the horse can jump. Hope this helped!

Answer (score -2):

I just built them with fences and gates and I put some hay and water inside each stall. ;-)